# Permanence of Dymo Labelwriter400 labels

Tags: barcode, label-printer

I have a Labelwriter400. I need to print barcodes that last decades. Can I do so with this unit, or do I need to get something else?

Comment: Questions seeking product recomendations are out of scope.  Furthermore, we can't predict if a label printed by any product, will last decades.

Comment: He is asking about his current Dymo LabelWriter and is asking a yes or no question.  The second part is asking for recommendations.  I think its a valid question... the first part at least.

Comment: @Keltari - Question should be modified so it's NOT asking for a product recommendation, only then should it be reopened, allowing additional answers.

Answer (score 2):

Dymo LabelWriter 400 are thermal printers.  This means heat can affect the label media its "written" on.  That, plus the material of the labels themselves have their own properties.  There are a number of different label media types.  I cant say for certain if any will last that long.  I would assume they would, as long as they are not exposed to heat, humidity, and intense light.

You should call up Dymo and see if they offer label media that meets your needs.